# How to get array input data using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My input field is as below:

```
<input type="hidden"  name="data[{{ $parentIndex }}][{{ $index }}]" value="{{ $value }}">
```

My sample data:

```
<input type="hidden"  name="data[0][0]" value="Name">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[0][1]" value="contact_email">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[0][2]" value="phone number">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[0][3]" value="contact_location">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[0][4]" value="">
                                                                                                                <input type="hidden"  name="data[1][0]" value="John Doe">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[1][1]" value="john.doe@example.com">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[1][2]" value="15551-234567">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[1][3]" value="New York, NY">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[1][4]" value="230">
                                                                                                                <input type="hidden"  name="data[2][0]" value="Jane Smith">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[2][1]" value="jane.smith@example.com">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[2][2]" value="15552345678">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[2][3]" value="Los Angeles, CA">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[2][4]" value="5201">
                                                                                                                <input type="hidden"  name="data[3][0]" value="Robert Johnson">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[3][1]" value="robert.johnson@example.com">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[3][2]" value="8.80156E+13">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[3][3]" value="Chicago, IL">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[3][4]" value="4110"
```

I was to access the data using below code:

```
var   data =$('input[name="data[]"]').map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

But it results empty array while I `console.log(data)` the data variable.

I have used following lines of code as well but it prints single array by combining the whole data.

```
var   data =$("input[name^='data']").map(function () {     return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

How do I get the array input here?

Comment: Maybe just search for `input[name^=data]` ("string starts with data") instead of looking for `data[]`, because the querySelector is looking for `input`s with the exact `data[]` string as its `name`, which it won't be if your templates inserts some stuff in there. `name="data[1]"`, for example, does not match the query `name="data[]"`. Only literally `<input name="data[]" />` matches that query.

Comment: i have tried with  `var   data =$("input[name^='data']").map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();` but it prints the data combindly instead of separate array ..

Comment: There's nothing built into JS or jQuery that will parse this into nested arrays. You'll need to write your own code that parses the `data[row][col]` names.

Comment: You can use regex selector in JQuery to parse them, based on your data the header field is listed on data[0] followed by data value in the next index. I just post the answer below, hope that help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of solving the issue. The form entries can be supplied by jQuery's `.serializeArray()` method or by using the Vanilla-JS's `FormData` class:

```js
const formEntries_vanillaJS=[...new FormData(document.getElementById("one")).entries()];
const formEntries_jQuery=$("#one").serializeArray().map(({name,value})=>[name,value]);

function processForm(arr){
 const o={};
 arr.forEach(([name,value])=>{
  const [nam,i,j]=name.split(/[\[\]]+/);
  if(j) { // we have TWO indexes for nam
   const t=o[nam]=o[nam]||[];
   (t[+i]=t[+i]||[])[+j]=value;
  } else o[nam]=value; // we have NO index for nam
 });
 return o;
}

console.log(processForm(formEntries_jQuery));
console.log(processForm(formEntries_vanillaJS));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<form id="one">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[0][0]" value="Name">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[0][1]" value="contact_email">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[0][2]" value="phone number">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[0][3]" value="contact_location">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[0][4]" value="">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[1][0]" value="John Doe">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[1][1]" value="john.doe@example.com">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[1][2]" value="15551-234567">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[1][3]" value="New York, NY">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[1][4]" value="230">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[2][0]" value="Jane Smith">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[2][1]" value="jane.smith@example.com">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[2][2]" value="15552345678">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[2][3]" value="Los Angeles, CA">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[2][4]" value="5201">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[3][0]" value="Robert Johnson">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[3][1]" value="robert.johnson@example.com">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[3][2]" value="8.80156E+13">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[3][3]" value="Chicago, IL">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[3][4]" value="4110">
<input type="hidden"  name="extraData" value="something else">
</form>
```

The function `processForm()` is just a simple implementation in which I assume that the `name` attribute of an `<input>` element can have either two indexes (i and j) or none. I then treat the `value` of the input element accordingly by either creating a sub- and sub-array for `nam` in `o` and placing `value` there or by storing `value` in the string-typed property `nam`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in css selector, based on example data :

```html
<input type="hidden"  name="data[0][0]" value="Name">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[0][1]" value="contact_email">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[0][2]" value="phone number">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[0][3]" value="contact_location">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[0][4]" value="zip_code">

<input type="hidden"  name="data[1][0]" value="John Doe">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[1][1]" value="john.doe@example.com">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[1][2]" value="15551-234567">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[1][3]" value="New York, NY">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[1][4]" value="230">

<input type="hidden"  name="data[2][0]" value="Jane Smith">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[2][1]" value="jane.smith@example.com">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[2][2]" value="15552345678">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[2][3]" value="Los Angeles, CA">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[2][4]" value="5201">

<input type="hidden"  name="data[3][0]" value="Robert Johnson">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[3][1]" value="robert.johnson@example.com">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[3][2]" value="8.80156E+13">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[3][3]" value="Chicago, IL">
<input type="hidden"  name="data[3][4]" value="4110">
```

And then use JQuery to map them :

```js
let data = [];

// Get headers
$("input[name^='data[0]'").map((pi, el) => {
    let head = $(el).val();

    // Get data rows based on index of header
    $(`input:not([name^='data[0]'])[name$='[${pi}]']`).map((i, pel) => {
    // Create new row for index 0 because the data row retrieved by index of header
    if(pi == 0) data.push({});
    let val = $(pel).val();

    // Map the value
    data[i][head] = val;
  });
});


console.log(data);
```

The idea is to map the header at the first row, and the data for the next row.

The header row has `data[0]` pattern, and not for the data row, so we can use `:not()` selector to exclude header row